# Find percentile using an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, percentile

I have a array like this

```
 array(
      45=>5,
      42=>4.9,
      48=>5,
      41=>4.8,
      40=>4.9,
      34=>4.9,
      .....
      )
```

Here index is `userid` and value is his score.

Now what i want is to achieve percentile for on user for example percentile of 45,48 would be 99 and 42,40,34 would be 97 and 41 would be 94.

How i can achieve this?

Comment: @MihaiIorga Its not `45.48`. He was trying to say that the users with ids 45,48 have 99 percentile since they got 5/5

Comment: So what do you want to do? Save it in a database? Put it in a flat file? Display it on a page? Assign it to an object?...

Comment: But still, there is not mathematical algorithm to achieve that.

Comment: I think he's trying to do a bell curve or something similar.

Comment: @all i want if two people get same score then their percentile would be same.

Comment: Please help me i m stuck in this??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Sort the array based on the "score", ascending
2. Percentile = (Index of an  element in the sorted array ) * 100 / (total elements in the array)

Example:

```
<?php
$array = array(
      45=>5,
      42=>4.9,
      48=>5,
      41=>4.8,
      40=>4.9,
      34=>4.9,
      );

print("Unsorted array:<br/>");
print_r($array);
arsort($array);
print("<br/>");
print("Sorted array:<br/>");
print_r($array);
print("<br/>");

$i=0;
$total = count($array);
$percentiles = array();
$previousValue = -1;
$previousPercentile = -1;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo "\$array[$key] => $value";
    if ($previousValue == $value) {
    $percentile = $previousPercentile;
    } else {
    $percentile = 99 - $i*100/$total;
    $previousPercentile = $percentile;
    }
    $percentiles[$key] = $percentile;
    $previousValue = $value;
    $i++;
}

print("Percentiles:<br/>");
print_r($percentiles);
print("<br/>");

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done a lot easier

```
function procentile($arr, $percentile=0.95){
    sort($arr);
    return $arr[round($percentile * count($arr) - 1.0-$percentile)];
}
```

Comment: If there are multiple elements in the array having the same value, this code will assign a different percentile number to each of those elements.

Comment: @Sameer I agree with you. Do you have any suggestion on how to bypass this?