# got wrong percentile calculation from array

Tags: php, arrays, percentile

hi there my problem is a bit complicated here.

I have a list of users who's average score is calculated by system and i want to rank them in percentile which is based on the average score rank  them in comparison to all other users  ie (total users) in (Top 20% to Bottom 20%).

Also the formula that i have studied and applied is the formula that get's my current position in all users that can be from 1 to 32 that is total number of users.

The formula is

```
($mycurrentPositionOutOfAllUsers / $totalNumberOfUsers ) * 100
```

but it always return false result as i am calculating it on online calculator on web https://www.easycalculation.com/statistics/percentile-rank.php

Also if i am doing some thing wrong please do suggest a soloution.
my array is

```
Array
(
    [ Lexington] => 6.49
    [ Davenport] => 5.66
    [ Romeoville] => 5.52
    [ Waterloo] => 5.46
    [ Lincoln] => 5.37
    [ Albert Lea] => 4.9
    [ Blaine] => 4.77
    [ Mason City] => 4.71
    [ Dubuque] => 4.64
    [ Rochester] => 4.59
    [ Des Moines] => 4.46
    [ Manitowoc] => 4.4
    [ Carroll] => 4.35
    [ Waukesha] => 4.34
    [ Eau Claire] => 4.31
    [ Norfolk] => 4.02
    [ Red Wing] => 4
    [ Durand] => 3.98
    [ St . Paul] => 3.81
    [ Mankato] => 3.75
    [ Clarksville] => 3.71
    [ Bismarck] => 3.65
    [ Indianapolis] => 3.63
    [ Cedar Rapids] => 3.56
    [ Fremont] => 3.55
    [ Omaha] => 3.5
    [ Fargo] => 3.5
    [ Grand Island] => 3.43
    [ LeRoy] => 3.32
    [ West Burlington] => 3.18
    [ Preston] => 3.06
    [ Blue Earth] => 2.71
)
```

Comment: Any code you would like us to see before we proceed?

Comment: Are you doing integer division? 1/32, 2/32, 3/32 will all return 0 with integer division.

Comment: i have applied his formula in my code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089984/find-percentile-using-an-array-in-php

Comment: faisal did you find the answer i am also struck in same situation .. the formula is not getting the right percentile